# Error: 'GetRandColor' is not declared. It may be inaccessable due to its protection level

Tags: html, vb.net

I have following error.
'GetRandColor' is not declared. It may be inaccessable due to its protection level.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Yes, _**show us the declaration for**_ `GetRandColor()`.

Comment: Please tell me how to do it...

Comment: Click on the edit link at the bottom of your question and add the code that you wrote to declare `GetRandColor`

Comment: Yes, and please read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why we need to see the declaration is that the error is telling you that it cannot find the definition of 'GetRandColor', and that possible it is because of the protection level of the function or class.

So, if you defined GetRandColor as

Private Function GetRandColor, or Protected Function GetRandColor, a Partial Class cannot 'see' the function.  You need to declare it as:

Public Function GetRandColor.

Now, the other issue could be that the Class is definited as Private or Protected, in which case you won't be able to see ANY of the functions in the class.  Of course, without SEEING the declarations, we have no way of knowing...